# Property requires method to be defined

Tags: objective-c, properties

I was converting a code from non-ARC to ARC, and removing some unnecessary @synthesize calls.
One specific class started issuing warnings for some properties:

Class.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *xyz;
```

but when building, I get the warning.

```
Property 'xyz' requires method 'xyz'to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation
```

I thought that using Xcode 4.6 and and Default Apple LLVM compiler 4.2, the @properties should be auto-synthesized.

How do I tell the compiler to auto-synthesize the property?
Do I have to use a specific project configuration to remove this warning?

Comment: Do you already have a `setXyz:` method?

Comment: P.S. For any future readers, remember to check spelling. It's easy to do something like `setPredence:` when the property is called `precedence`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is this property on an `NSManagedObject` subclass? `NSManagedObject` disables auto-synthesis precisely because most declared properties are expected to be `@dynamic`.

This is accomplished with the `NS_REQUIRES_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS` macro placed right before the `@interface NSManagedObject`, which expands to `__attribute__((objc_requires_property_definitions))`. This could be used on other classes too, but `NSManagedObject` is the only framework class I know of that does this.

Comment: Indeed it is! That was the issue, I didn't know this particularity with `NSManagedObject` class.